# Specification that C++ enums are default constructible?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17

C++ enumeration types appear to be "default constructible":

```
enum UE { a=1, b, c };
enum class SE { a=1, b, c };

int main() {
    UE ue;
    SE se;
}
```

How can this be explained from the standard?

I mean - let's say we wanted to change the standard to make it so they weren't default constructible.  Which clauses would change?

Comment: They are just like `int` or `float`. If you define a non-static local variable of the type, it will be *uninitialized* and its value will be *indeterminate*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Yeah I know.  What's the standard reference for that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's all in [[dcl.init]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init#7):

> To default-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> - If T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type, constructors are considered. The applicable constructors are enumerated
>     ([over.match.ctor]), and the best one for the initializer () is chosen
>     through overload resolution. The constructor thus selected is called,
>     with an empty argument list, to initialize the object.
> - If T is an array type, each element is default-initialized.
> - Otherwise, no initialization is performed.

`UE` and `SE` match the third bullet, like fundamental types. So the initializaiton is simply a no-op, and they are left with an indeterminate value.

This is also the bullet list you'd need to tackle first to make enumerations not default initializable.

Answer (score 2):

Don't let the `class` in `enum class` confuse you: It is still considered a non-class type. The syntax for *scoped enums* just happens to co-opt the `class` keyword, so as not to add yet another reserved word to the language.

Answer (score 1):

There is a draft specification here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/n4778.pdf

See section 9.6, Enumeration declarations.

I think you may be coming from Java, in which enumerations are classes. In C++, enumerated values are just integer constants. The type of the constant is generally `int` although it can be explicitly defined.

Since the enumeration is just an `int`, when you declare one without an initializer, there's no default constructor involved; you just get an uninitialized `int`.

Comment: Can you declare overloaded operators on enums?

Comment: @curiousguy: You can overload any operators that don't require a member function. For instance, you could overload `+=` using non-member operator overloading, but you can't overload `->`.

Comment: "_Since the enumeration is just an int_" how can you overload on it? You can't overload on `int`.